# how to stop a function by li

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make when i click in the body the li function returns i did logo id just for test

```js
let li = document.getElementById("li");
let ul = document.getElementById("ul");
let img = document.getElementById("img");
let logo = document.getElementById("logo");
var cancelled;

// I want clicking on the body to stop this function
let i = li.onclick = setInterval(function() {
  ul.style.transition = ".5s";
  ul.style.visibility = "visible";
  li.style.color = "var(--Almost-Black)";
  img.style.transition = ".5s";
  img.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
  ul.style.top = "30px";
}, 1000)

logo.onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(i)
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo" id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="li" id="li"><a href="#">Features</a> <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" id="img">
          <ul class="ul" id="ul">
            <li><img src="images/icon-todo.svg" alt=""> To do list</li>
            <li><img src="images/icon-calendar.svg" alt=""> calendar</li>
            <li><img src="images/icon-reminders.svg" alt=""> Reminders</li>
            <li><img src="images/icon-planning.svg" alt=""> planning</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="btns">
        <button class="login"><a href="#">login</a></button>
        <button class="reg"><a href="#">Register</a></button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay do you know how can i make this for every time and thanks for your respnose

Comment: The value of `li.onclick` must be a function. You're calling `setInterval()` immediately, not when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `li.onclick` must be a function. You should assign the interval to `i` inside the function, not when assigning `onclick`. You should also clear the old interval first, in case it's clicked twice.

If you want to click on the body instead of the logo to cancel, use `document.body.onclick`. You also need to call `event.stopPropagation()` in the `li.onclick` so that clicking on the LI doesn't bubble out to the body.

```js
let li = document.getElementById("li");
let ul = document.getElementById("ul");
let img = document.getElementById("img");
let logo = document.getElementById("logo");
var cancelled;
let i;

// I want clicking on the body to stop this function
li.onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  clearInterval(i);
  i = setInterval(function() {
    ul.style.transition = ".5s";
    ul.style.visibility = "visible";
    li.style.color = "var(--Almost-Black)";
    img.style.transition = ".5s";
    img.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    ul.style.top = "30px";
  }, 1000);
};

document.body.onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(i)
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <div class="logo" id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="li" id="li"><a href="#">Features</a> <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" id="img">
          <ul class="ul" id="ul">
            <li><img src="images/icon-todo.svg" alt=""> To do list</li>
            <li><img src="images/icon-calendar.svg" alt=""> calendar</li>
            <li><img src="images/icon-reminders.svg" alt=""> Reminders</li>
            <li><img src="images/icon-planning.svg" alt=""> planning</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="btns">
        <button class="login"><a href="#">login</a></button>
        <button class="reg"><a href="#">Register</a></button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clever but can you explain the code more

Comment: I'm not sure what more to say than I already wrote. Which part of it are you confused by?

Comment: look i knew your code thank you so much because it's clean but do you know how do i make when i am clicking on the body this function returns

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, I thought it was about clicking on the LI.